# Dropdown menu that contains more than one topic

Tags: lists, dropdown, tags, sort

I'm trying to figure out what is the best solution for dropdown menus that contain more than one topic.
For instance, if I want to view and add at one field all the users and the groups created at the platform, I've added tabs to the dropdown that would show the "Groups" list separately and the "Users" list separately.
 - it functions as a multiple-choice dropdown.
 - there is a general search field that would search both at "Groups" and "Users"
 - Near the name of the topic, I show inside brackets the number of objects selected

What do you think?
Is everything clear?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the community. 
Why don't you try something like an accordion attached?

The pros of having this accordion are that you can see which user is in which group.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the help!
I think its a bit missing the use case.
The end-user doesn't want to know which member being at which group.
sometimes the end-user has many groups with a lot of people in it so the accordion will be a bit cumbersome I think.
The user should simply choose which groups and users he wants to add.